# How to decrypt a Gravatar hash into real email address?

Tags: php, cryptography, gravatar

I need to grab the real email address from a Gravatar URL that shows the avatar image:

> http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fbca892a7c5f5e6a99ad33433f5a93d0?d=http%3A%2F%2Fs.intensedebate.com%2Fimages%2Favatar-normal.png&s=26&r=PG

Comment: I think that the whole point is to make that impossible!

Comment: It's an MD5 hash, so nearly impossible. If you have a database of target email addresses (for a subset of Gravatars) then it is possible. You _could_ brute-force search for this, but it will be slow, and may be regarded as a privacy violation by some of these Gravatar users.

Comment: I think it can be done but I can't, in some article it said that "fbca892a7c5f5e6a99ad33433f5a93d0" contained the email address.                                                                               http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/07/got-an-account-on-a-site-like-github-hackers-may-know-your-e-mail-address/

Comment: Yes. Powerful adversaries with substantial computing resources can brute-force search an MD5 hash for an email address. The generated tables can be stored permanently, making future searches faster. If you don't know the Gravatar owners, and do not have permission to do this, then you should not try. In terms of computing power and storage, it is likely out of your reach anyway.

Comment: This is not a "brute force" search.  The space of possible email addresses is too large for a brute-force attack.  What they are doing is buying or harvesting lists of known email addresses from various sources, and generating MD5's and storing them.  If you have the list of email addresses, then the computing power and storage required is modest.

Comment: Note to future readers: In the years since 2015, computing power has only increased, high-powered systems become more available, and cracking tools more powerful and easier to access & use, meaning that MD5 hashes have only gotten easier to brute force in the meantime. This is also due to the fact that we're talking about hashes of _emails_ here, which means that attackers can make good assumptions regarding the contents of a Gravatar hash before even starting to crack it (eg. that it ends with `@[common-email-provider.tld]`). Do your research, and don't consider MD5 secure.

Comment: Re the previous comment: This problem can't be blamed on the weakness of MD5.  Gravatar hashes would have the same problem if they just used SHA256 (for example) instead of MD5.  (The weakness in MD5 means that it is computationally feasible to create a second source text that has the same MD5 as an existing one.  But that kind of attack is not at the root of Gravatar's problem.  The Gravatar problem is that the existing source text (email addresses) are often known or guessable before hand, so you can create and store the corresponding hashes in a database and do a reverse lookup.)

Answer (score 10):

Gravatar hashes are generated as described here: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/

As you can see, the hash is effectively an MD5 hash of the email address.  MD5 hashes cannot be "decrypted".

So the answer is ... you can't do it.

However, if you know what the email address is (or is likely to be) you can generate the hash and compare it with the one you already have.

---

> I think it can be done but I can't, in some article it said that "fbca892a7c5f5e6a99ad33433f5a93d0" contained the email address.

Sorry, but you are incorrect in your belief.  The gravatar hash does not "contain" the email address, and if some article really said that, then it is wrong.  And for the record, [the article you linked](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/07/got-an-account-on-a-site-like-github-hackers-may-know-your-e-mail-address/) to does NOT say that.  What it is describing is a kind of "rainbow table" attack that matches hashes with *previously known* email addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Because email addresses are widely shared, this is quite easy, assuming you have access to lists of leaked customer data which contain the email of the Gravatar you're looking for.

According to haveibeenpwned.com, my own email address occurs in 17 different breaches. Some of these are services I have used, and some of them are breaches of companies who obtained my email without my knowledge or consent. Unlike passwords, you can't really change your email address if it shows up in a breach.

Think about how many websites and services have your email address. Now, think about how many of those websites have lax security, or misplace your data. The odds that your email address has shown up in a breach [are pretty much guaranteed](https://www.troyhunt.com/the-773-million-record-collection-1-data-reach/).

Assuming you can build a database of email addresses, you can take the MD5 of each email address. You only need to build the database once, and after that you can very cheaply check whether a gravatar URL matches any of the email addresses you've seen before.

The other answer points out that it is impractical to brute-force MD5 for sufficiently high-entropy input. This is absolutely correct, but it misses the point. You don't need to brute-force email addresses, because email addresses are generally not secret. On the other hand, associations between accounts and email addresses sometimes *are* secret.

Gravatar's decision to design their service in a way which allows this attack is fairly appalling from a privacy perspective.

More resources:

- 10% of StackOverflow Gravatars can be reversed by trying combinations of the user's name plus popular email providers. [Link](http://www.developer.it/post/gravatars-why-publishing-your-email-s-hash-is-not-a-good-idea).
- 45% of email addresses on a French political forum could be de-anonymized. This was done using hashcat. He used a list of popular email providers for the domain name. To determine the left hand side, he used a combination of dictionaries, and bruteforcing short usernames. [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdphoc3XUF8) to talk by Dominique Bongard.
- Overview of this issue. [Link](https://www.wordfence.com/blog/2016/12/gravatar-advisory-protect-email-address-identity/)
- In 2020, an undocumented API allowed anyone to enumerate all of Gravatar's users, and obtain the MD5 sums of their email addresses and display names. Of the 167 million hashes obtained this way, 114 million of them were ultimately cracked, for a success rate of 68%. (Source: HIBP)

Comment: "quite easy" is relative here. Yes, hackers with a ton of resources can do it, [and it is a serious problem](https://www.wordfence.com/blog/2016/12/gravatar-advisory-protect-email-address-identity/). On the other hand, doing this won't be easy for OP as an average stackoverflow user.